# Kotlin - How to find and cast an element by its type

Tags: kotlin

I have a collection of objects which inherit `Component` and I want a function which finds an object by its concrete class and return it.
But Kotlin does not like the cast I do, and adding `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` is ugly.

I have the following code:

```
open class GameObjectImpl : GameObject {
    private val attachedComponents = mutableSetOf<Component>()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <TComponent : Component> getComponent(type: KClass<TComponent>): TComponent? {
         return attachedComponents.find { type.isInstance(it) } as? TComponent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
open class GameObjectImpl : GameObject {
    val attachedComponents = mutableSetOf<Component>()

    override inline fun <reified TComponent : Component> getComponent(type: KClass<TComponent>): TComponent? {
         return attachedComponents.filterIsInstance<TComponent>().firstOrNull()
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, Kotlin has that already built-in, I did not know that.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to make `TComponent` `reified` (and `attachedComponents` `public`) or use `filterIsInstance(type.java)` in order to make this compile.

Comment: @mfulton26 Ah yes, forgot that `filterIsInstance` requires a reified parameter. Thanks, answer updated.